# simple todo app, can't connect to mlab db - node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mlab

I am following this tutorial and for some reason I am being refused a connection from the mlab db that I have created.
MongoError: failed to connect to server [ds129260.mlab.com:29260] on first connect

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var todos = require('./routes/todos');

var app = express();

// View Engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/api/v1/', todos);

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server started on port 3000...');
});
```

routes/todos.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('mongodb://aaron:aaron@ds129260.mlab.com:29260/todosmeanaarondev',['todos']);

// Get Todos
router.get('/todos', function(req, res, next){
    db.todos.find(function(err, todos){
        if(err){
           res.send(err); 
        } else {
           res.json(todos);
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Unsure if there is another way of retrieving the db. Thanks

Comment: The server denoted in the error message is different than the server in your code.... odd?

Comment: Didn't notice that, I was trying something new. I fixed the question, am getting the same response

Comment: You most likely have a network related issue. Maybe firewall? Because I can connect to that db with your code locally.

Comment: ah ok you're probably right then. thanks

Comment: FYI for folks reading at home, we (mLab) have published a connection troubleshooting guide here: http://docs.mlab.com/connecting/#help

Answer (score 0):

Install the database locally.  99% the same.

Connection String:

```
var db = mongojs('mongodb://test:test@127.0.0.1:27017/todos',['tasks']);
```

1. Open New Terminal, execute "Mongod" (daemon)
2. Open Another Terminal execute "Mongo",  From there you can check the IP 
   and Port number to connect.

https://treehouse.github.io/installation-guides/mac/mongo-mac.html
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/